# Chrome Web notification 'MismatchSenderId' error

Tags: google-chrome, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I have deployed the [sample code](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/push-notifications) for Chrome push notifications and updated the `gcm_sender_id` to a newly configured project, the client is able to subscribe/unsubscribe without issue but when posting a request to send a notification the response `MismatchSenderId` is continually returned.

I have tried creating multiple new projects `console.firebase.google.com`, but nothing seems to work.

Request:

```
POST /gcm/send HTTP/1.1
Host: android.googleapis.com
Authorization: key=<Server Key/>
Content-Type: application/json
{
    "registration_ids":[
        "<Registration-ID/>"
    ]
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "multicast_id": 6881038306061588882,
  "success": 0,
  "failure": 1,
  "canonical_ids": 0,
  "results": [
    {
      "error": "MismatchSenderId"
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

I am using the 'Server Key' as the request auth token (which works as 401 is returned when an invalid key is used) and am using the 'Sender ID' in the manifest:

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Notification Demo",
  "gcm_sender_id": "<Sender ID/>"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was my own fault; the sample registration ID's were in a different format to the generated ones I was seeing and did not contain semicolons which I was using to strip the registration ID from the subscription endpoint string. Splitting the endpoint by a forward slash and taking the last instance returned the correct Registration ID which works fine.